# Access id of first foreach loop in second loop when where condition is met

Tags: laravel, foreach, where-clause

```
$data['customers'] = DB::table('master_customer')->where('ORG_ID', $user_org)->get();//customer table

$document_cat = DB::table('document_category')->get();//category table

foreach ($data['customers'] as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($document_cat as $key1 => $value1) {

        $docs = DB::table('master_documents')//docuements saved in this table
            ->where('cust_id', $value->id)
            ->get();
        $document_cat[$key1]->doc = $docs;

    }

    $data['customers'][$key]->documents = $document_cat;
}

print_r($data);
die;
```

Comment: I could not understand your question, could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: are you getting any error. Also what are you getting dd($value)?

Comment: What "_third_" loop are we talking about here?

Comment: @matheen I'm trying to get $value->id but its value is not working in where clause

Comment: @ Sehdev when i put static value where('cust_id', 206) then result appears

Comment: check  what is the value of  echo  $value->id

Comment: @Sehdev when i echo value->id  its giving me 206206205205207207203203212212

Comment: @VikasSingh is this correct customer_id?

Comment: @Sehdev yes this is customer id

Comment: @Sehdev I have to append customer's documents on customer array on the key of documents with category of documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you dont update eloquent relationships in models? If you do so it could be much easier.

MasterCustemer Model

```
public function masterDocuments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\correctfoldertoothermodel\MasterDocument','cust_id');
}
```

MasterDocument Model

```
public function masterCustomer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\correctfoldertoothermodel\MasterCustomer','cust_id');
}

public function documentCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\correctfoldertoothermodel\DocumentCategory');
}
```

DocumentCategory Model

```
public function masterDocuments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\correctfoldertoothermodel\MasterDocument');
}
```

Of course you'll have to provide the correct table names in migration for auto implementation of fk or set tables in relationships too.

When it's done you could retrieve data like it:

```
$masterCustomers->with('masterDocuments.documentCategory')->get();
$masterCustomers->masterDocuments = $masterCustomers->masterDocuments->groupBy(function($item){
   return $item->documentCategory->name;
});
```

The result will be a collection of customers with and property containing an another collection of categories with its documents.